# R - images saved with rgl.snapshot turn blank after dev.off()

Tags: r, png, rgl

I have x, y, z coordinates for 15 markers that were collected via motion capture. I'm using the rgl package to create 3D images of the markers, and I would like to export each image as an individual png file. The motion capture recordings are 5-15 seconds in length, and I'm exporting images of the coordinates at a frame rate of 120 fps. So, I have to export 600-2000 images per recording.

I have written a loop that is supposed to plot the coordinates in each frame and save an image of each plot as a png. However, the "saved" images I'm getting are only temporary files - when I give dev.off(), the images disappear and the saved files convert to blank pages. Clearly there is something I'm misunderstanding about how to handle devices & write permanent image files!

I understand that rgl uses its own devices, and I've tried giving rgl.close() instead of dev.off() when the maximum device number is reached (i.e. after 63 images are exported). But without also giving dev.off(), I continue getting the "too many open devices" error.

My code looks like this:

```
for (i in seq(1,nrow(opti),by=2)) {
   tframe <- data.frame(matrix(cbind(opti[i, c(seq(1,43,by=3))], 
                                opti[i, c(seq(2,44,by=3))], 
                                opti[i, c(seq(3,45,by=3))]), 
                                nrow = 15, ncol = 3))
   par3d("windowRect" = c(0,0,1200,800))
   png("filename", res = 600, width = 1200, height = 800)
   plot3d(tframe$X1, tframe$X2, tframe$X3, size = 4, box = F, axes = F, 
        xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = "")
   segments3d(x = as.vector(tframe$X1[c(5,6)]),
              y = as.vector(tframe$X2[c(5,6)]),
              z = as.vector(tframe$X3[c(5,6)]))
   segments3d(x = as.vector(tframe$X1[c(5,7)]),
              y = as.vector(tframe$X2[c(5,7)]),
              z = as.vector(tframe$X3[c(5,7)]))
   segments3d(x = as.vector(tframe$X1[c(6,7)]),
              y = as.vector(tframe$X2[c(6,7)]),
              z = as.vector(tframe$X3[c(6,7)]))
   rgl.snapshot("filename")
}
```

And here is a sample frame:

```
tframe <- data.frame(matrix(c(1775.061, -1210.373, 901.3876, 2007.21,
             -1324.62, 786.1902, 2021.581, -1122.637, 787.6369, 2020.769,
             -1214.902, 953.5361, 1832.449, -1226.912, 1281.304, 1721.739,
             -1207.299, 1225.152, 1839.68, -1116.221, 1208.916, 1869.173,
             -1362.631, 1017.457, 1958.79, -1364.152, 972.9478, 1784.636,
             -1489.286, 738.0247, 1874.096, -1460.005, 834.2597, 1880.647,
             -1091.414, 1032.096, 1979.333, -1059.292, 958.2598, 1796.085,
             -914.6528, 747.6667, 1865.53, -945.6564, 817.4066), 
             nrow = 15, ncol = 3, byrow = T))
```

How do I go about writing permanent image files that do not turn blank when devices are closed?

Comment: `png(~)` is unnecessary. Did you possibly name all files "filename" ? If so, let's use `filename <- paste0("pic", formatC(i, digits = 3, flag = "000"), ".png")` and `rgl.snapshot(filename)` instead of `rgl.snapshot("filename")`.

Comment: `png()` is not just unnecessary, it's harmful. It opens a file for base graphics to write to.  Then `rgl.snapshot()` writes to that file.  Then when you call `dev.off()`, base graphics writes the nonexistent plot to that file, wiping it out.

Comment: @user2554330; Thank you for your supplementary explanation.

Comment: Yes, thank you both. Removing the png() and adding a periodic graphics.off() works perfectly.